# Jinja template variable syntax

Tags: python, jinja2

What is the difference between the following 2 template variable assignment?

```
{% set active_page = 'index.htm' %}
---vs---
{% set active_page = 'index.htm' -%}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one will remove the white space after it. As the [document](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#whitespace-control) says:

> You can also strip whitespace in templates by hand. If you add a minus sign (`-`) to the start or end of a block (e.g. a For tag), a comment, or a variable expression, the whitespaces before or after that block will be removed:
>
> ```
> {% for item in seq -%}
>     {{ item }}
> {%- endfor %}
> ```
>
> This will yield all elements without whitespace between them. If seq was a list of numbers from 1 to 9, the output would be `123456789`.

Comment: Thank you! It is very difficult to search for these kind of things in Google directly.